# Android studio not showing preview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to set up android studio but it is not showing the device preview. I am unable to add a device to display.[image: preview]

Also have many other errors since downloading the new version.

Comment: Please check your SDK path, bcoz it shows null in image.

Comment: how do I check it?

Comment: Go to File -> Project Structure & see SDK Location is correct or not.